# Check in the setter if an Enum is one of the desire element

Tags: java, enums, setter

I want to validate an argument passed into the setter.

I have an Enum and in this Enum I have a car colors.

In the setter I  want to check if the passed in argument is a part of my Color enum.

I am looking for any enum method but I haven't found any. I tried to use regex but this was not good idea.

```
public enum Color {
  BLUE, RED, BLACK, WHITE
}

public void setColor(String color) {  
  //hear should be a method checking if a color contain enum  
  this.color = color;
}
```

I expect that this element will be contain an enum.

Comment: In what sense do you suppose `color`, a `String`, could "contain" an enum?  Any enum?

Comment: When you call `Color.valueOf(color)`, you'll get an `IllegalArgumentException` if the string `color` is not a name of a `Color` value. Isn't that enough? And... Why not make `setColor` take a `Color` instead of a `String`?

Comment: An `enum` is a type. `public void setColor(Color color)`

Comment: should contain my enum - colors -BLUE, RED, BLACK, WHITE

Comment: Or at least, if ```setColor``` needs to convert from a ```String``` for some reason, declare ```this.color``` as type ```Color```, and handle the exception if the argument is out of range.

Comment: Why not make `setColor(Color)` rather than `setColor(String)`?

Comment: Ok now I have: public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

Comment: OK thanks I understand that I shouldn't have a String in return statement

Comment: Did you mean “setter” by “Seter”?

Comment: Yes Basil I mean Seter in pojo class

Comment: Thank You satnam to make my question more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

> In the setter I want to check if the passed in argument is a part of my Color enum.

Wrong approach. You should be **passing an object**, one of your enum objects, rather than the text of the name of the color.

See the `poster.setBackgroundColor( Color.GREEN )` example below.

That is the main point of using enums in Java: To **let the compiler check** at compile-time if a valid value was passed, rather than you worrying about validation in your code at runtime.

## Details

Looks like you are mixing up some things. You may be mixing up the enum instance (a constant), its hard-coded name, and a name you may want to display to the user at runtime.

An `Enum` is a way to conveniently instantiate a predetermined number of instances of a class, each instance being assigned a predetermined name. For example, [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html), with [`Month.JANUARY`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html#JANUARY) through `Month.DECEMBER`.

## Constant name

If you want that hard-coded name of the instance, in all uppercase by convention (as a constant), then call `toString`.

```
String constantName = Month.JANUARY.toString() ;
```

> JANUARY

Be very clear here: The `String` object with the text “JANUARY” was generated by the `Month` object named `JANUARY`. **The `Month` object and the `String` object are entirely separate and distinct.** The text of the `String` is merely a representation of the value of the `Month` object.

If you want to obtain the constant by that hard-coded instance name, call `valueOf`.

```
Month m = Month.valueOf( "JANUARY" ) ;  // Returns a `Month` object, not text.
```

Try to *not* make a habit of `valueOf`. Calling `valueOf` defeats the purpose and power of enums in Java. You should be **passing around the enum objects**, not a string of their names.

## Display name

Those all-uppercase English values may work well enough for logging and debugging. But we do not likely want all-uppercase English text to appear in our user-interface and reports. So when writing your own `Enum`, add a method named something like [`getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)), as seen on `Month` & [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html). Specify `TextStyle` for the length of abbreviation, and `Locale` for the human language and cultural norms used in translation.

```
String output = m.getDisplayName( 
    TextStyle.FULL , 
    Locale.CANADA_FRENCH 
) ;
```

> janvier

How to implement that on your own enum? Well, your enum is actually a subclass of [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html). So your enum is actually a Java class like any other, in that it can have constructors and methods. Add arguments to each declared enum instance name.

## Example class

Here is a complete example enum class in a single `.java` file, with a `main` method to demo.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Set;

public enum Color {
    BLACK( "Black" ),                       // Pass arguments to each declared constant instant name, as you are really calling the constructor on each `static` `final` class constant object being automatically instantiated.
    GREY( "Grey" ),
    RED( "Red" ),
    GREEN( "Green" ),
    BLUE( "Blue" );

    private String displayName;             // Store the display name as a member variable on each enum instance.

    // Constructor     
    Color ( String displayName ) {          // Define a constructor taking the display name argument you passed above.
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    String getDisplayName ( ) {
        return this.displayName;
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( "Color.BLACK.toString(): " + Color.BLACK.toString() );
        System.out.println( "Color.BLACK.getDisplayName(): " + Color.BLACK.getDisplayName() );

        Set < Color > monochromeColors = EnumSet.of( Color.BLACK , Color.GREY );
        boolean isRedMonochrome = monochromeColors.contains( Color.RED ); // ➙ false.
        System.out.println( "isRedMonochrome: " + isRedMonochrome );
    }
}
```

When run.

> Color.BLACK.toString(): BLACK
>
> Color.BLACK.getDisplayName(): Black
>
> isRedMonochrome: false

Notice the use of `EnumSet` (or `EnumMap`) to collect enum instances. Here we defined a collection of `Color` objects in a `Set` named `monochromeColors` for the black and grey colors, but ignoring the red, green, and blue colors.

To use your enum, imagine a `Poster` class with a setter method for the background color of the poster.

```
Poster poster = new Poster() ;
poster.setBackgroundColor( Color.GREEN ) ;
```

### No need for text – just use objects

Notice that there is **no text involved**. There is no need for string of the name of the instance, nor any need for the display name. Using an enum instance is about using an object, not text, not a `String`. Using the enum object ensures valid values, provides [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), and makes your code more self-documenting.

### Using names

Let's add code needing those names. First for logging, add a `toString` method on `Poster`.

```
@Override public String toString() {
    return "Poster{ name=" + this.name + " | backgroundColor: " + this.backgroundColor.toString() + " }" ;  // Shows "GREEN"
}
```

When presenting the poster in the user-interface, show the name of the color.

```
Label label = new Label( 
    "Background color: " + 
    poster.getBackgroundColor().getDisplayName()   // Shows "Green".
) ;
```

Comment: Thanks In first i create an color like a String but next I create an Enum and I don't change it in Pojo so it's a reason of mistake.